# Frames without scrollbar, but whole window should have one

Tags: html, scrollbar, frames

Please, is it possible to have 3 horizontal frames, with a total height bigger than the screen height?

There should be a scroll bar on the side of the window, but only one scroll bar for the whole window.

I tried

```
<frameset rows = "350px,350px,350px" scrolling="yes">
```

Then

```
<frame name = "top" 
  src = "TopFrame.html" 
  border = 0
  frameborder = "0"
  scrolling="no"
  />
```

But this only functions as long as I don't start filling up the other frames. When I fill them up, the top one gets resized.

Subsidiary question : do I really need 3 frames or is it possible to insert a frame in a page with stuff in its body? I tried iframe but what I write below the frame doesn't show up.

I need the middle part to be reloadable without reloading the whole page. I didn't manage to do that with jQuery so now I'm trying frames instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add `scrolling="no"` on the `iframe`

```css
iframe {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://blog.54ka.org/" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://blog.54ka.org/" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://blog.54ka.org/" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The frame in the middle of the page is written :

```
<iframe name = "middle" 
src = "MiddleFrame.html" 
border = 0
frameborder = "0"
scrolling="no"
>
Sorry your browser does not support inline frames.
</iframe>
```

and in the head part you add :

```
<head>
<style>
body {
  height: 5000px; /* Makes this site really long */
  width: 98%; /* Makes this site wide but with no horizontal scrollbar*/
  overflow: auto; /* Shows scrollbars when needed */
}

</style>
</head>
```